# Combining sheets into one PDF

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel sheets with account numbers from 1 to 600.

I want to print all sheets together in a single pdf. It means the pdf would contain 600 bills.

What is the VBA code for this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is simple. Only workbook export to pdf file.

```
Sub test()

    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim myFn As String
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, i As Integer
    Set WB = ThisWorkbook

    For i = 1 To 600
        With Sheets(i)
            .Range("C5") = i 'Account No  cell
        End With
    Next i

    myFn = WB.Path & "\" & "test.pdf"

    WB.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, myFn
End Sub
```

Comment: I need individual sheets of PDF means bills 1.pdf 2.pdf 3.pdf to 600.pdf and combine all files to single pdf file.

Comment: @MahanteshAmbole: this is single pdf contain every sheet.

Comment: @MahanteshAmbole: you mean one specific sheet at number 1 to 600, and export as Pdf?

Comment: if your attention is that, my answer is not suitable.

Comment: yes, i want 600 sheets for every sheet account number change and also infromation linked with formulae

Comment: if you apply to every sheets then upper code is useful.

Comment: @MahanteshAmbole: modified my answer.